# Run-Install python-meep Error

Tags: python, meep

I am new in python meep. I try to use python-meep on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit (virtual machine).
I install all the necessary things like PCRE  swig and python meep, but when I try to run  the samples it gives me the same error as in the beginning:

```
 ~/Desktop/Python/python-meep/samples/bent_waveguide$ python python_meep_bent_wg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_meep_bent_wg.py", line 21, in <module>
    from meep import *  # make it 'meep_mpi' for MPI-meep and 'meep' for non-MPI meep
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/meep.py", line 4693, in <module>
    import scipy.weave
ImportError: No module named scipy.weave
```

(about scipy I have a problem to install it - I get the message:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: python (<< 2.6)
```

... so I install it with `dpkg -i`, and then made some updates but in the end I have some kind of broken packages)

Right now I am really stuck and have no idea what to do. Maybe somebody has an idea how to fix it or install it correctly overcoming all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the python-setuptools, so you install the stuff with pip or easy_install.